# Find time lag between two SQL records with SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, lag

I have the following requirement.  I have an application that logs a status for a machine. This record is inserted every 30 minutes for that machine into a table.

I can get the lag between the current and previous record, but I need to check if there is a lag of 400 minutes before the next record gets written.

In other words, there is a record every 30 minutes, but a new record for that machine might not write again for a day or more as the machine is down.  I need to therefore check the current record and if 400 mins has elapsed and the next record is not written send a warning that the machine has been down for 400 mins or more.

My lag statement is as follows:

```
SELECT  
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, pDataDate, q.a_Timestamp) AS [Duration],
    q.Machine, q.a_Timestamp, q.DownCode
FROM    
    (SELECT  
         *,
         LAG(a_Timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY a_Timestamp, Machine) pDataDate
     FROM    
         dbo.TireroomDownTime) q
WHERE   
    pDataDate IS NOT NULL 
    AND q.DownCode <> 0 
    AND q.DownCode <> 98 
    AND q.Emailed <> 1
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: If I understand your correctly you don't need `lag` you need `datediff` between now and the most recent record?

Comment: My lag statement is just to show the calc that gives me the duration between two records.  What if a record is written and I want to check if the next record written for the same machine is 400 mins or more.

Comment: Your questions says "I need to therefore check the current record and if 400 mins has elapsed and the next record is not written" i.e you want to check whether 400 mins has passed since the last record was written... you don't say you want to check if the duration between 2 records is more than 400mins.

Comment: If there is only one record, how do I check if the next record is not written > 400 mins.

Comment: Where is the green checkbox that is mentions.  I dont see anywhere to select the question as answered, hence the reason they are still open.

Comment: Accepted an answer.  Other questions dont have the tick box.

Comment: As I mentioned above, get your latest row per machine, and then use datediff to check how many minutes have elapsed.

Comment: And you can now upvote/downvote as your reputation is high enough.